# Get the value of an item in a tensor in Tensorflow.js

Tags: indexing, tensor, tensorflow.js

How do I get the value out of a tensor in Tensorflow.js after specifying the index?

Answer (score 21):

You can use datasync for this.

```
const newTensor = tf.tensor2d([[2,4],[5,6]]);
const tensorData = newTensor.dataSync();
console.log("data[0] is " + tensorData[0]);
console.log("data[3] is " + tensorData[3]);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NMKgeO?editors=1011

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following more powerful method

> tensor.buffer().get(0, 0);

This will allow you index into logical coordinates of the tensor (the 2d coordinates as opposed to the flattened 1d coordinate). See the [link](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msgid/tfjs/6b2f6ba2-0dbe-4676-af92-5c8d617e874e%40tensorflow.org.)

Comment: How would you do that in python Tensorflow Keras?

Answer (score 2):

```
const newTensor = tf.tensor2d([[2,4], [5,6]])
newTensor.get([0]) ##returns 2
newTensor.get([3]) ##returns 6
```

Thankfully, all this returns a number and not a tensor.

Comment: It doesn't work: **Error: Number of coordinates in get() must match the rank of the tensor**.

Comment: @JavaRunner can you share the code/tensor it doesn't work with?

Comment: This `get` function no longer exist in latest version.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.Tensor.dataSync()` does not retain the original shape. If you would like to preserve the shape, you can use `tf.Tensor.arraySync()`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also use slice to get the value:

```
let value = tensor.slice([i,j], [1, 1]);
```

or

```
let value = tensor.slice([i,j], [1, 1]).arraySync()[0][0];
```